# How to make the user save a text box value as an image or file to their machine in html5 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to make the user save a text box value with out the use of server side scripting . I am using html5 and jQuery . I tried printing the textbox by putting it inside an iframe with print() function of javascript and it worked , I want to know whether any other alternatives are available .

Comment: Using html5 canvas to add the text to canvas and then saving the canvas as image using toDataUrl() method

Comment: @anu Thanks , I tried that but am getting a checkered flag like background , any way to avoid that ?

Comment: You can try adding a background image.